# Echoing output in Netlogo (from extensions)

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make an extension in Netlogo. it is easy to make a method that invokes a function that returns a value using  org.nlogo.api.Reporter  But sometime functions have side effects and write output in the standard output chanel. How can I make things so that the output is written or is redirected to the Netlogo command center?  For example, there is the extension Netprologo that allows me to invoke SWI-Prolog. So if I invoke the predicate "write(6)" Netlogo receives the predicate output which is true or false (i.e. the predicate execution result) but actually the 6 (the side effect) is not written in the command center of Netlogo.   Best

Comment: Also asked at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/netlogo-devel/tX-tZVN8Hac/Eqmx5CwQBwAJ

Comment: I believe this is mainly a question about the NetProLogo extension and about how it interacts with SWI-Prolog. To the extent that part of your question is NetLogo-specific, Bryan has already answered that part. For the rest, you might try taking it up with the author of the extension? I know nothing about either NetProLogo or SWI-Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`Workspace.outputObject`](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.x/src/main/org/nlogo/workspace/AbstractWorkspace.java#L451) is what you're looking for. Checkout the code for [`print`](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/ea7bc6306eba6d47df2fd9126594ae8868c6695a/src/main/org/nlogo/prim/etc/_print.scala) and [`show`](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/ea7bc6306eba6d47df2fd9126594ae8868c6695a/src/main/org/nlogo/prim/etc/_show.scala) for a couple of examples of how to use it. In both cases, the `args(0).report(context)` thing is just the thing to be printed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I can capture input from the command line also? Do you know Prolog and the trace command that allows us to trace the execution of a prolog predicate issuing commands while code is executing step by step.In fact we make trace. than we execute the predicate and while Prolog is executing the same predicate we can interact with the interpreter. It would be great to capture input form the command center also.

Comment: Bryan, if Paulo was able to capture the output from Prolog in the first place, then your answer would be the necessary last step for making that output appear in NetLogo's command center. But I think the problem he's having is getting a hold of that output in the first place.

Comment: Yes I will have first to get a hold of the output coming from Prolog execution and then redirect it to Netlogo command center output window. I will try Bryan suggestion